# What does rotational balance mean?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, terminology

For example, in many badminton rackets, it says that the balance point is rotational. How does this actually work?

Comment: Could be the same way a sword is balanced (i.e. no in the middle but according to how it works when swung. There's a sweet spot were the impact point speed is balanced against force when swung

Comment: Yea, I agree with your analogy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but here is a guess. It may mean the racket is dynamically as well as statically balanced about the balance point. The racket is balanced statically in that the racket is stationary with a fulcrum at the balance point. The racket is dynamically balanced in that rotation (spinning the racket) about a principal axis through the balance point is steady without requiring a restraining torque.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was reading about the dynamic balancing mechanism, got the basic idea, now I can connect the dots.

Comment: Principal axes do not have points associated with them, they are directions.

Comment: The three principal axes have an origin in the body, and points in the body lie along each principal axis.  I said the balance point lies along a principal axis; after more thought, I think the balance point is at the origin of the principal axes.  What do you think?